# Split List by Date

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to figure out a way to split a list containing dates. I'm going to try an explain this as simple as possible.

[image]

So in the picture above List 1 is the original list, and list 2 is the new list. However the new list can be any other selection of the 7 days in this grid.

the result would either be 2 new lists or 3 new lists. 2 if the new list begins or finishes  the original list. 3 if it happens to split it as in the picture.

in the case of the picture above, the result would be;

- list 1 : from 2-Jan to 2-Jan
- list 2 : from 3-Jan to 5-Jan
- list 3 : from 6-Jan to 6-Jan

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this work with a private enum to keep track of the status between the matching dates of the two lists:

```
Private Enum DateStatus
  NoMatching
  OneMatching
  AllMatching
End Enum

Private Function SplitDates(listOne As IEnumerable(Of Date), _
                            listTwo As IEnumerable(Of Date)) _
                          As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Date))
  Dim results As New List(Of List(Of Date))
  Dim listStatus As DateStatus = DateStatus.NoMatching

  Dim startDate As New Date(Math.Min(listOne.First.Ticks, listTwo.First.Ticks))
  Dim finalDate As New Date(Math.Max(listOne.Last.Ticks, listTwo.Last.Ticks))
  Dim curDate As Date = startDate
  While curDate <= finalDate
    If listOne.Contains(curDate) And listTwo.Contains(curDate) Then
      If listStatus <> DateStatus.AllMatching Then
        listStatus = DateStatus.AllMatching
        results.Add(New List(Of Date))
      End If
    ElseIf Not listOne.Contains(curDate) And Not listTwo.Contains(curDate) Then
      listStatus = DateStatus.NoMatching
    Else
      If listStatus <> DateStatus.OneMatching Then
        listStatus = DateStatus.OneMatching
        results.Add(New List(Of Date))
      End If
    End If
    If listStatus <> DateStatus.NoMatching Then
      results.Last.Add(curDate)
    End If
    curDate = curDate.AddDays(1)
  End While
  Return results
End Function
```